# MySQL query value + 1

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want update column in the table with specific values automatically increasing, i used this query :

```
Update wp_postmeta 
set meta_value = 11622 + 1
WHERE  `meta_key` =  '_thumbnail_id'
ORDER BY  `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` ASC
```

its work but all values in meta_value column become equal, anyone can help?

Comment: Why doing ORDER BY on Update?

Comment: You can specify a column as an "auto increment" in MySQL id "meta_key" is your "id" field.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update wp_postmeta 
set meta_value = (meta_value + 1)
WHERE  `meta_key` =  '_thumbnail_id'
```

Comment: You want the meta_value to increase every time? Then you have to use the 2nd code.

Comment: Yes I want to increase every time

Comment: Them of course you have to change it to INT, it is a number isn't it? Otherwise how would you want to increase it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sql, and "ORDER BY" is not needed in the "update" sql.

```
Update wp_postmeta 
set meta_value = meta_value+1
WHERE  `meta_key` =  '_thumbnail_id'
```

Comment: @LoaiMostafa What's the means of the every time ?